# Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

I already install python and I add it to path. But when I run `python3 setup.py sdist` in Windows power shell it said `Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.`
I also do the answers on some similar questions but it still not work.
Please help me, thanks very much.

Comment: Try typing in `py` instead of the full `python`. It installed like that for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make following steps:

- Create virtual env in your project`s directory:

  python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
- Try to use python, py instead of python3